# Delete a div id using ajax and jquery and delete from DB

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've got several div id's, each containing a different client.  I want to be able to click the delete button and using ajax and jquery delete the specific div from the database. I'm getting success in AJAX but it's not deleting anything from the DB. And then obviously, upon deletion, I would like the container to reload dynamically. help!!!

```
function DeleteClient(){
clientID = $('.clientblock').attr('id')
alert(clientID);
 var yes = confirm("Whoa there chief! Do you really want to DELETE this client?");

 if (yes == 1) {
 dataToLoad = 'clientID=' + clientID + '&deleteclient=yes',

 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: '/clients/controller.php',
 datatype: 'html',
 data: dataToLoad,
 success: function(html) {
 alert('Client' + clientID + ' should have been deleted from the database.');
 $('#clientscontainer').html(html); 
 },
 error: function() {
 alert('error');
 }});};
 };

controller.php info //
Variables necessary are:
$deleteClient
$clientID

on the delete click, when being passed through post (via firebug)
clientID = 0
deleteClient = yes
```

edit: so obviously, it's not getting the correct client ID to delete it to the DB as it is passing through post but I am getting an ajax success call and where i have the client ID variable displaying there, it is picking the correct client ID.

```
 
alert(clientID) is pulling in 0 as well.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to put some info about your controller.php here.
Try to use Firebug to track the post to the controller to see whats happening - the parameters, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataToLoad = 'clientID=' + clientID + '&deleteclient=yes',
```

Your controller is getting clientID value of 0.

Track down your clientID javascript variable and see if it is fetching the correct clientID.

Comment: I was able to get it to correctly identify the clientID variable and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks!